# Asset and theme

Tags: php, pyrocms

I'm trying to figure out why after adding in the this asset line it turns into the line below it but shows a 404 file not found when in fact it does exist.

Asset::css('theme::bootstrap/bootstrap.css');

http://dev.myurl/application/themes/mytheme/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css” rel=“stylesheet”>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php 
Asset::css('bootstrap/bootstrap.css');
echo Asset::render(); 
?>
```